# when i start the local dev server using "npm run dev" it shows ERR

Tags: vue.js

I GOT THIS ERROR
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'E:\work\MW Website\mwwebsite\build\webpack.dev.conf.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: webpack.NamedModulesPlugin is not a constructor

MY PACKAGE.JSON {
"webpack": "^5.82.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.8.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.1.0",
"webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"

i am working on vuejs